# Seleccionar y extraer de popen al main

Tags: c, dns

Pues bien, tengo esta función extraerDns que me consigue, por fin, lanzar una llamada al sistema que me devuelve la salida de un comando netsh, que es completado por el valor de mi variable "adaptador", recogido por el usuario mediante teclado y ya utilizada en un módulo anterior.
Por lo visto (si cambio en mi código "adaptador" por, pongamos, el número relativo al adaptador en cuestión), mi función está operativa y devuelve el resultado esperado:

```
char extraerDns(const char* adaptador)
{
    char* c, * end;

    strcpy(str, "netsh interface ipv4 show dnsservers ");
    strcat(str, adaptador);
    FILE* dns = _popen(str, "r");
    if (!dns) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, dns)) {
        if (!strstr(line, "DNS")) {
            continue;
        }

        c = strchr(line, ':');
        c += 3;

        end = c;
        while (*end != '\0') {
            end++;
            if (!isdigit(*end) && *end != '.') {
                break;
            }
        }

        *end = '\0';
        strcpy(str, c);
    }
    _pclose;
    return 0;
}
```

Pero a la hora de implementarlo en mi main es donde me encuentro problemas:

```
    int exportarAdaptadores(char *adaptador);
    printf("\n\n    DNS a comparar: %s.\n", str);
    int dnsvelocidad = velocidad_media(str);
    printf("\n\n    Velocidad media: %s ms.\n", dnsvelocidad);
```

Finalmente, mediante la variable "str", obtengo imprimir el resultado que quiero, es decir, un servidor DNS correctamente, tipo 80.80.80.120 y sin espacios entre los caracteres (que es lo primero en lo que me he fijado). Sin embargo, a la hora de pasar por mi función velocidad_media, que expongo a continuación, el programa deja de funcionar y obliga a cerrarlo. He revisado las variables globales, he ajustado el tamaño de "str", pero no veo en qué puede residir el error:

```
int velocidad_media(const char* ip)
{
    const char* const Delim = "Media = ";
    printf("\nExtrayendo velocidad media de %s", ip);

    char cmd[64];
    sprintf(cmd, "ping %s", ip);
    FILE* p = _popen(cmd, "r");
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), p))
    {
        char* s = NULL;
        if ((s = strstr(line, Delim)) != NULL)
        {
            _pclose(p);
            return atoi(s + strlen(Delim));
        }
    }
    _pclose(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sí, es extraño, porque en un bloque anterior hay llamada a dicha función y se resuelve sin problema...

Comment: ¡Ya está, @Trauma!
%s para printar un entero... no way. ¡Disculpad el desliz!

Comment: He publicado mi propia respuesta ya que no me es posible eliminar mis propios hilos todavía (sólo editar). Si algún moderador lo lee y considera conveniente eliminarlo, adelante. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

```
int dnsvelocidad = velocidad_media(str);
printf("\n\n    Velocidad media: %s ms.\n", dnsvelocidad);
```

Intentaba printar un entero (dnsvelocidad) con %s en lugar de %d, de ahí mi error.
Ya está solucionado.